# How to reach the next li a from a specific point

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to change link color to the button below the id `#idTERRITORIAL_8` which has the class `.active_default`, the `idIMMUNOLOGY_9`, but I cannot use that directly. My starting point has to be `#idTERRITORIAL_8`.

I tried this :

```
$('#idTERRITORIAL_8').parent().find('.active_default').addClass("red");
```

But all `.active_default` changed color.

I also tried `next` and `nextAll`

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <ul class="menu">
     <li><a href="#" id="idOVERVIEW_1" class="">Overview</a></li>
     <li><a href="#" id="idSALES_2" class="">Sales</a>
        <ul>
           <li><a href="#" id="idNATIONAL_3" class="">National</a></li>
           <li><a href="#" id="idPROVINCIAL_4" class="">Provincial</a></li>
           <li><a href="#" id="idREGIONAL_5" class="">Regional</a>
              <ul>
                 <li><a href="#" id="idIMMUNOLOGY_6" class="active_default">Immunology</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#" id="idCOAGULATION_7" class="">Coagulation</a></li>
              </ul>
           </li>
           <li><a href="#" id="idTERRITORIAL_8" class="">Territorial</a>
              <ul>
                 <li><a href="#" id="idIMMUNOLOGY_9" class="active_default">Immunology</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#" id="idCOAGULATION_10" class="">Coagulation</a></li>
              </ul>
           </li>
           <li><a href="#" id="idDEPOT_11" class="">Depot</a></li>
        </ul></li>
     <li><a href="#" id="idICP_12" class="">ICP</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Your javascript looks like it should work - you may want to do some debug printing? There may be a problem with your html formatting. Try: `$('idTERRITORIAL_8').parent().css('border', '20px solid red')` - should mark the desired parent so you can see what you're really targetting.

Comment: Works in my side https://jsfiddle.net/jnwrc5ay/21/.

Answer (score 1):

```
  $('#idTERRITORIAL_8').next().find('.active_default').addClass("red");
```

Link to jsbin example:

https://jsbin.com/lenotolaco/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Thank you! I missed it.
It works perfectly

         var btn_subsubmenu = $(this).next().find('.active_default');
         if ($(btn_subsubmenu).hasClass('active_default')) {
            $(btn_subsubmenu).addClass('active');
         }